# Meteor reading a file in public folder using readFileSync not working when deployed

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to read a .json file in /public folder. Relative path I'm using is '../../../../../public/data.json' and it works when I run with `meteor run`.

However, when I deploy to meteor subdomain by running `meteor deploy MyApp.meteor.com`, it crashes and the logs say

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '../../../../../public/data.json'

I tried using 'data.json', 'public/data.json', etc. but I couldn't get it to work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Put the data in a "private" directory off of your app root instead of "public" (assuming that you're only going to read it on the server, which is what you seem to be doing). When you want the file (regardless of if you are deployed or not), it is at the path "assets/app/".

For example, if your app had the directory structure:

```
myApp.css
myApp.js
myApp.html    
server/
    serverCode.js
private/
    data.json
```

You could use something like "peerlibrary:fs", which exposes fiber aware fs sync functions, and do the following in "serverCode.js"

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("assets/app/data.json"));
```

Comment: Just to clarify, if you are running locally, your app runs in a directory that is called (from your app root): ".meteor/local/build/programs/server", which is where you'll find the "assets/app" directory, which contains a copy of the contents of the "private" directory.

Comment: If you want to keep it in the "public" directory, then use "../web.browser/app/" as a path prefix when deployed. You already stated how to reach it when you're not deployed. Because it's different whether or not you are deployed, that is a less desirable solution than the one in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the file data.json in the root of the public folder you can just use the path "/data.json"

Comment: I already tried but getting error like this:   (STDERR) Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/data.json'

Comment: That's if you're making an http GET request to the server, but not if you're opening a file from the server code.